# What is the best way in rails to build a version of time ago in words with but with different formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to build a version that can be localized and I need different versions of the text.

Where is the best place to these functions so they can be accessed from my view code?

Where do I find the source for the original code?

Comment: I hope I explained this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Where to put it: `ApplicationHelper` (app/helpers/application_helper.rb) is probably the best place.

The original code: `time_ago_in_words` lives in `DateHelper` ( http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html ), and is based on `distance_of_time_in_words`. Here's a link to Github: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/bd8a9701c27b4261e9d8dd84aebbde6ba784ed83/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L67

That said... it looks to me as though DateHelper already interfaces with i18n. You should make sure you really need to duplicate this functionality.